# How to autogenerate Pydantic field value and not allow the field to be set in initializer or attribute setter

Tags: python, pydantic

I want to autogenerate an ID field for my Pydantic model and I don't want to allow callers to provide their own ID value. I've tried a variety of approaches using the `Field` function, but the ID field is still optional in the initializer.

```py
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    item_id: str = Field(default_factory=id_generator, init_var=False, frozen=True)
```

I've also tried using `PrivateAttr` instead of `Field`, but then the ID field doesn't show up when I call `model_dump`.

This seems like a pretty common and simple use case, but I can't find anything in the docs for how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a combination of a `PrivateAttr` field and a `computed_field` property:

```py
from uuid import uuid4
from pydantic import BaseModel, PrivateAttr, computed_field


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    _id: str = PrivateAttr(default_factory=lambda: str(uuid4()))

    @computed_field
    @property
    def item_id(self) -> str:
        return self._id


print(MyModel().model_dump())
```

Comment: I was thinking about a computed field. Is the PrivateAttr even needed if I'm using a computed field?

Comment: Yeah, you might omit the private field, but then you'd have to have another mechanism to guarantee that the id is generated only once

Answer (score 0):

You can override `__init__` and tweak it however you want before validation takes place. It's a simple and flexible approach:

```py
from uuid import uuid4

from pydantic import BaseModel


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    item_id: str

    def __init__(self, **data) -> None:
        data["item_id"] = str(uuid4())
        super().__init__(**data)


print(MyModel().model_dump())
```

Note that you must call the parent's `__init__` at the end so that the changes happen before the validation.

Comment: This wouldn't stop someone from add the `item_id` when initializing the model, though. It actually would require that field, but then ignore it. I want a validation error if someone includes the `item_id`.